# How to extend LINQ select method in my own way

Tags: linq

The following statement works fine if the source is not null:

```
Filters.Selection
            .Select(o => new GetInputItem() { ItemID = o.ItemId })
```

It bombs if "Filters.Selection" is null (obviously).  Is there any possible way to write my own extension method which returns null if the source is null or else execute the "Select" func, if the source is not null.

Say, something like the following:

```
var s = Filters.Selection
                .MyOwnSelect(o => new GetInputItem() { ItemID = o.ItemId })
```

"s" would be null if "Filters.Selection" is null, or else, "s" would contain the evaluated "func" using LINQ Select.

This is only to learn more about LINQ extensions/customizations.

thanks.

Comment: It might make more sense to have `s` be an empty sequence instead of `null`, as that would allow you to chain other extension methods off it safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
public static IEnumerable<U> SelectOrNull<T,U>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, Func<T,U> map)
{
    if (seq == null)
         return Enumerable.Empty<U>(); // Or return null, though this will play nicely with other operations
    return seq.Select(map);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about LINQ to Objects, absolutely:

```
public static class NullSafeLinq
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> NullSafeSelect<TSource, TResult>
        (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
    {
        // We don't intend to be safe against null projections...
        if (selector == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");
        }
        return source == null ? null : source.Select(selector);
    }
}
```

You may also want to read my [Edulinq blog post series](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx) to learn more about how LINQ to Objects works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes have a look at the Enumerable and Queryable classes in the framework, they implement the standard query operators.

You would need to implement a similar class with the same Select extension methods matching the same signatures, then if the source is null exit early, you should return an empty sequence.